# Most Efficiently Written Query in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables, Table1 and Table2 and am trying to select values from Table1 based on values in Table2. I am currently writing my query as follows:

```
SELECT Value From Table1
WHERE
(Key1 in
    (SELECT KEY1 FROM Table2 WHERE Foo = Bar))
AND
(Key2 in
    (SELECT KEY2 FROM Table2 WHERE Foo = Bar))
```

This seems a very inefficent way to code the query, is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Looks pretty good to me (as long as there are no NULL values in the "key" columns). Why do you think it's inefficient? Is it slow? Have you checked the execution plan?

Comment: @ypercube do you really think doing it the OP way is better than a join?

Comment: @eis depends on the DBMS, the indexes available and many other things. For semi-joins (as here) I prefer `EXISTS` subqueries.

Comment: Unless the matching `Key1` and `Key2` values are on the same records in Table2,  two IN statements is likely your best option.

Comment: @eis, it may be better than a join depending on the number of duplicate records and the correlation between `Key1` and `Key2` in `Table2`

Comment: @ypercube: Just as an aside, NULLs wouldn't be a problem (perhaps you were thinking of *NOT* IN).

Comment: @AndriyM Yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how the table(s) are indexed. And it depends on what SQL implementation you're using (SQL Server? MySq1? Oracle? MS Access? something else?). It also depends on table size (if the table(s) are small, a table scan may be faster than something more advanced). It matters, too, whether or not the indices are *covering indices* (meaning that the test can be satisfied with data in the index itself, rather than requiring an additional look-aside to fetch the corresponding data page.) Unless you look at the execution plan, you can't really say that technique X is "better" than technique Y.

However, in general, for this case, you're better off using *correlated subqueries*, thus:

```
select *
from table1 t1
where exists( select *
              from table2 t2
              where t2.key1 = t1.key1
            )
  and exists( select *
              from table2 t2
              where t2.key2 = t1.key2
            )
```

A join is a possibility, too:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
join table2 t2a = t2a.key1 = t1.key1 ...
join table2 t2b = t2b.key2 = t1.key2 ...
```

though that will give you 1 row for every matching combination, though that can be alleviated by using the `distinct` keyword. It should be noted that a join is not necessarily more efficient than other techniques. Especially, if you have to use `distinct` as that requires additional work to ensure distinctness.

Comment: +1 `EXISTS()` is way faster and more efficient on subqueries than `IN()`

Comment: @eis: now you're arguing about what what columns get included in the result set, not the semantics of the query.

Comment: @NicholasCarey I'm not arguing anything, just saying if OP wants just a column, star is not warranted for. Yes, I know it is trivial, but even trivial polishing does make sense time to time. Not all comments are about challenging the answer, some are actually trying to improve it.